# C# Failed to save settings: The configuration file has been changed by another program

Tags: c#, exception, settings

I have just release a program (OptiKey) which passes lambdas used to get, set, and save user settings within a single class:

The lambdas are passed from this class (from line 143):
https://github.com/JuliusSweetland/OptiKey/blob/master/src/App.xaml.cs

To this class:
https://github.com/JuliusSweetland/OptiKey/blob/master/src/Services/WindowManipulationService.cs

N.B. The "set" lambda updates the setting's value (e.g. Settings.Default.Whatever = X) and then calls Settings.Default.Save()

I CANNOT replicate the crashes locally, but I am receiving crash reports from users where the call to Save is throwing an exception, which I catch and handle by reloading the settings from disk, and then attempting the save again. This is not working and the retry is throwing exceptions also.

I have been told that this happens even when users are not using virus scanners (which I thought might be locking the user.settings file).

Any ideas? This is the biggest cause of crashes that I have, and I've no idea how to reproduce it!

```
The configuration file has been changed by another program. (C:\Users\Charlie Sheen\AppData\Roaming\JuliusSweetland\OptiKey.exe_Url_2dm1ifc0wqzcnmfgnsyhbssrcdx5zgbz\2.0.5.0\user.config)

<SerializableException xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ExtendedInformation>
    <HResult>-2146232828</HResult>
  </ExtendedInformation>
  <InnerException>
    <ExtendedInformation>
      <BareMessage>Failed to save settings: The configuration file has been changed by another program. (C:\Users\Charlie Sheen\AppData\Roaming\JuliusSweetland\OptiKey.exe_Url_2dm1ifc0wqzcnmfgnsyhbssrcdx5zgbz\2.0.5.0\user.config)</BareMessage>
      <Line>0</Line>
      <Errors>System.Configuration.ConfigurationException[]</Errors>
      <HResult>-2146232062</HResult>
    </ExtendedInformation>
    <InnerException>
      <ExtendedInformation>
        <BareMessage>The configuration file has been changed by another program.</BareMessage>
        <Filename>C:\Users\Charlie Sheen\AppData\Roaming\JuliusSweetland\OptiKey.exe_Url_2dm1ifc0wqzcnmfgnsyhbssrcdx5zgbz\2.0.5.0\user.config</Filename>
        <Line>0</Line>
        <Errors>System.Configuration.ConfigurationException[]</Errors>
        <HResult>-2146232062</HResult>
      </ExtendedInformation>
      <Message>The configuration file has been changed by another program. (C:\Users\Charlie Sheen\AppData\Roaming\JuliusSweetland\OptiKey.exe_Url_2dm1ifc0wqzcnmfgnsyhbssrcdx5zgbz\2.0.5.0\user.config)</Message>
      <Source>System.Configuration</Source>
      <StackTrace>   at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.SaveAs(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceUpdateAll)
   at System.Configuration.Configuration.SaveAsImpl(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceSaveAll)
   at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.WriteSettings(String sectionName, Boolean isRoaming, IDictionary newSettings)</StackTrace>
      <TargetSite>Void SaveAs(System.String, System.Configuration.ConfigurationSaveMode, Boolean) @ System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord</TargetSite>
      <Type>System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException</Type>
    </InnerException>
    <Message>Failed to save settings: The configuration file has been changed by another program. (C:\Users\Charlie Sheen\AppData\Roaming\JuliusSweetland\OptiKey.exe_Url_2dm1ifc0wqzcnmfgnsyhbssrcdx5zgbz\2.0.5.0\user.config)</Message>
    <Source>System</Source>
    <StackTrace>   at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.WriteSettings(String sectionName, Boolean isRoaming, IDictionary newSettings)
   at System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.SetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyValueCollection values)
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.SaveCore()
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.Save()
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Save()
   at JuliusSweetland.OptiKey.App.&lt;App_OnStartup&gt;b__18(Double t) in c:\Users\Julius\Documents\GitHub\OptiKey\src\App.xaml.cs:line 251
   at JuliusSweetland.OptiKey.Services.WindowManipulationService.PersistDockThickness() in c:\Users\Julius\Documents\GitHub\OptiKey\src\Services\WindowManipulationService.cs:line 1003
   at JuliusSweetland.OptiKey.Services.WindowManipulationService.PersistSizeAndPosition() in c:\Users\Julius\Documents\GitHub\OptiKey\src\Services\WindowManipulationService.cs:line 1026
   at JuliusSweetland.OptiKey.Services.WindowManipulationService.ApplyAndPersistSizeAndPosition(Rect rect) in c:\Users\Julius\Documents\GitHub\OptiKey\src\Services\WindowManipulationService.cs:line 523</StackTrace>
    <TargetSite>Void WriteSettings(System.String, Boolean, System.Collections.IDictionary) @ System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore</TargetSite>
    <Type>System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException</Type>
  </InnerException>
  <Message>Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.</Message>
  <Source>mscorlib</Source>
  <StackTrace>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)</StackTrace>
  <TargetSite>System.Object InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean) @ System.RuntimeMethodHandle</TargetSite>
  <Type>System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException</Type>
</SerializableException>
```

FYI settings are also accessed (get/set+save) in a couple of other places in the code - perhaps simultaneously, but I don't think this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solved this per se. Instead I've avoided changing and saving settings in quick succession. Now I change the settings in the global static savings class and save on application exit.